# кеширование страницы

Tags: html, vue.js

Имеются 3 страницы веб приложения. 3 файла .html
хотелось бы максимально сократить время ответа сервера путём кеширования остальных для быстрого переключения между ними уже без обращения к серверу (это может показаться не нужным ) но в моём случае это будет полезно

пойдёт и фоновая загрузка после index.html

хотелось бы узнать, какими инструментами я могу реализовать такой функционал.

сервер не на хостинге а на esp модуле. предустановки для хостинг серверов не подойдут, если таковые имеются

Comment: Есть браузерный кеш - достаточно добавить правильные заголовки. Тогда у конкретного пользователя после первой загрузки ресурса, повторные обращения к нему будут из кеша браузера. А есть серверное кеширование - браузер запрашивать ресурс будет, но сервер не будет генерировать страницу, а просто возьмет ее из кеша. Вам какой вариант нужен? Одна и та же страница одинакова точь-в-точь для разных посетителей?

Comment: Нет, страницы будут разные. полагаю искать информацию в сторону браузерного кеша.

в таком случае, можно чуть подробнее про заголовки

Comment: https://web.dev/http-cache/#cache-control